# select and fill an object in a bidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I have made a bidimensional array, and for each index I have created an object and fill it with a color.
I want to select a single item from this array, and fill it with a different color, but my solution doesn't work, how can I do this?

This is the code (in the HTML file the JavaScript is after `<canvas>`):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    width = canvas.width = 400,
    height = canvas.height = 400;

var cols = 10,
    rows = 10,
    w = width / cols,
    h = height / rows;

var grid = new Array(cols);

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    grid[i] = new Array(rows);
}

for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        grid[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        grid[i][j].fill(255,255,255);
        grid[i][j].show(1);
    }
}
//This square should be black
grid[4][4].fill(0,0,0);

function Cell(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.fill = function(r, g, b){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
    };

    this.show = function(stroke){
        rect(this.x * w, this.y * h, w, h, stroke);
    }
}

function rect(x,y,w,h,s){
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
    if(s){
        ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Your english (and your coding skills) are very good for your age!

Now to your problem: your `grid[4][4].fill(0,0,0);` call changes the fill-style of the canvas-context but doesn't actually draw over the already painted canvas. You have to either call `grid[4][4].show(X);` again afterwards or have the `fill()` method call `show()` automatically.

I also found a potential error in your code: You made the first dimension of your Array be `cols`, and then made the fori loop that filled it with the inner Arrays loop over the `rows` as indexes (size of array X, access Y fields).

Answer (score 0):

@Michael-Ritter beat me to the answer.

The state gets updated but not re-rendered. 
*This is where Angular's two-way data binding comes in handy.
Or Reacts re-rendering techniques.*

I'm not used to canvas, so an eventListener seems to be missing.
This is what I've added to your code. [Heres a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oju8mg84/).

```js
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var x = Math.round(e.clientX / w);
  var y = Math.round(e.clientY / h);
  grid[x-1][y-1].fill(100, 100, 100);
  grid[x-1][y-1].show();
});
```

Comment: setting the fill-style is actually nothing else than selecting a color in the color-palette. You need to actually use a tool to paint afterwards. There are no listeners for that unless he implements some on his own that watches a cell's values and automatically redraws that cell (his own class)

Answer (score 0):

like above, you have to call your `show()` function again to actually draw over the tile already there.

your code is a bit verbose with all of the `for` loops in there.  i simplified it a little bit here: https://jsfiddle.net/rkstar/x3o1zyfb/

basically it just uses your last for loop and colors the tile black as it is created in the loop instead of trying to do it after.